# Understanding Model-View-Controller

Tags: objective-c, arrays, model-view-controller

I am teaching myself Objective C, and I am trying to progress with the idea of model-view-controller. My question is: what is the correct way of creating data in a model class? I have an example to illustrate what I mean, it's a bit long but a really simple question.

The following code is from a memory game I just finished. It works fine, I have separated the data from the view controller and so I have a separate class to hold the images for the cards. Here is that class. By the way, it all works, the only thing important for my question is that there is an array declared so feel free to skip most of the code that does the duplicating of the images and randomising. Anyway, here it is:

## import "Cards.h"

@implementation Cards

```
- (NSMutableArray*) createCardImages{
    
    NSMutableArray *Fruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Banana.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pear.png"],         
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Strawberry.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lemon.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange.png"],        
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pineapple.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Kiwi.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Prune.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Peach.png"],
                        nil];

    NSUInteger tileCount = [Fruits count];
    
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
        NSInteger nElements = tileCount - i;
        NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [FullList exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
    
        NSArray *Shortlistprep1 = [Fruits subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    
        NSArray *ShortListprep2=[Shortlistprep1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:Shortlistprep1];

    
        NSMutableArray *ShortList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
        ShortList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ShortListprep2];
    
    return ShortList;
}

- (NSMutableArray*) shuffleCards{
    
    
   NSUInteger cardCount = [self.cardImages count];
    
    NSMutableArray *count = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
    for (int tileID = 0; tileID < cardCount; tileID++){
        [count addObject:[NSNumber
                                       numberWithInt:tileID]];
    }
    
        return count;
}
```

Then I call this method from the view controller and it all works.
Next, I would like to add a different list of images so that different sets of images can be chosen when playing the game. Something like:

```
NSMutableArray *Clothes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hat.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Coat.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gloves.png"],         
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Trousers.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Socks.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sweater.png"],        
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"T-shirt.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Shirt.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Jumper.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Underwear.png"],
                        nil];
```

I know I could just duplicate the whole method for each new set, something like this:

```
  - (NSMutableArray*) createCardImagesClothes{
        
         NSMutableArray *Clothes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hat.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Coat.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Gloves.png"],         
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Trousers.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Socks.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sweater.png"],        
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"T-shirt.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Shirt.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Jumper.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"Underwear.png"],
                        nil];

        NSUInteger tileCount = [FullList count];
        
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
            NSInteger nElements = tileCount - i;
            NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
            [FullList exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
        }
        
            NSArray *Shortlistprep1 = [FullList subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
        
            NSArray *ShortListprep2=[Shortlistprep1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:Shortlistprep1];
    
        
            NSMutableArray *ShortList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
            ShortList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:ShortListprep2];
        
        return ShortList;
    }
```

And I am fine with doing this if this is the way forward, I just would like to learn best practices. I feel like there should be a way to just write one method and then have the properties declared on the h file as so:

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    
    @interface Cards : NSObject
    
    // Create Cards
    @property NSMutableArray *cardImages;
    @property NSMutableArray *shuffledCards;

   @propery NSMutableArray *Fruits;

   @propery NSMutableArray *Clothes;

   @propery NSMutableArray *SomeOtherSet;

   @propery NSMutableArray *SomeOtherSet;

   @propery NSMutableArray *SomeOtherSet;
    
    - (NSMutableArray*) createCardImages;
    - (NSMutableArray*) shuffleCards;

    @end
```

and then all I would have to do is modify my method to accept an argument of the type NSMutableArray, like so:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) createCardImages:(NSMutableArray);
```

And just call the method with the argument which would represent whatever set I want to load.

My question, and it's a fairly basic one, is where would I actually load information into those arrays. There is no "main" or "viewDidLoad" method on the "m" file to actually load the data -in this case the images- into the array.

Does that make sense?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: whatever your goal is, you may need to be aware of that _model_ layer stores/restores/manages the data only (e.g. -`create...`), but any further interactions with the data are initiated on the _controller_ layer (e.g. `-shuffle...`) logically, so for shuffling the deck it would be more reasonable to create a category on `NSMutableArray` – but obviously that is based on subjective opinion only – as there are no strict rules of why you should do so.

Comment: @holex - actually, in standard MVC, the Model layer encapsulates the data and all operations associated with that data. I would call `shuffle` definitely a normal operation on a deck of cards, which should go in the Model layer. The Controller layer only contains the functionality required to map the Model to the View.

Comment: @fishinear, actually that is primary opinion-based, because the developer decides where the _model-layer_ ends and where the _controller-layer_ begins; __the only rule__ here is each layer must be replaceable without affecting the other two layers; like e.g. on the _model_ the app stores everything in a local `plist` files initially but you need to replace the storing engine with CoreData + iCloud for a reason, therefore then that kinda changes must not affect the _controller_ or _view_ layer at all – if it affects and those can't be the same, then the current MVC pattern is completely wrong.

Comment: @holex - all design is opinion-based. The "only rule" that you mentioned is actually the normal data encapsulation rule of all OO-design. But the well-established MVC design pattern has specific roles assigned to each of the layers. But this is not the place to discuss this. Feel free to PM me if you want to discuss it further.

Comment: thanks holes I see what you are saying. I will look into creating a category on NSMutableArray, not something I have done before. How would I load the images into the array on the card class though?

Comment: @fishinear, your interpretation of the "one rule" is not particularly so simple; the _model-layer_ of a huge project is never a simple class (nevertheless I hardly image any project which has only one class as model-layer); but let us say we develop a _camera_ app, in that case the _model-layer's_ job only create the empty canvas, and the _controller-layer_ populates that canvas by colours from the camera; you can find more more "anomalies" even in `UIKit`, like why the `UINavigationController` is not on the _view-layer_ but on the _controller-layer_, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguably you shouldn't be exposing the mutable array, your model should be a better container for the data and actually operate on the data. Shuffling by returning an array of numbers doesn't actually change the data model and it should.

Also, it would be cleaner if your data model dealt with data management, not the explicit creation. If you had a factory class which could be asked to generate a set of images and supply those images for your `Cards` class to deal with you would separate your concerns better. You could add class methods to `Cards`, or an instance method which took an enum to decide which images to use, but the images are really a separate issue to the management of those images as cards.

So, the view controller, when it's created to manage a game, asks the factory class for an instance of `Cards` for a specified image type. Once it has that `Cards` instance it can shuffle it and then request the card at a specified index, or grid location.

Index and grid location are interesting parts, because that could be different for different game types. Different game types can all use the same set of cards (though with a different `Cards` instance), but index those cards in a different way. To support this it's good to offer a simple index into the cards and allow the controller which knows the game logic to decide how to use that index system.

In all of the above the controller never accesses the cards as an array. The interface is similar, but all interaction is with `Cards` and that class hides its internal structure. Internally it would use an array, but it could use something else and the controller shouldn't care.

Comment: This is a really good answer as far as I can tell but for my level right now a little too abstract. I will have to study it and I will. I realise that I am going in the right direction but still at the beginning. I can see what you are saying about the data not being modified in the class. Could you explain in simple terms how to actually load images into the @property NSMutableArray *fruits; in the actual Card m file? If I was doing it in the view controller all i'd do is cards.fruits = and load a set of images under viewDidLoad, but there is no "viewDidLoad" in the cards class.

Comment: the trigger is in the controller to start the whole process, it calls a method on the factory / `Cards` class. ideally that method would be an initialiser, not a plain setter, because the cards should't be directly mutable after creation of the `Cards` instance

Comment: so, to get this straight, are you saying that my only option is to actually load the images in the view controller when i initiate the instance of cards? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of model? sorry if I am way out, i am trying to get this. tx

Comment: it depends how much you're interested in changing. mainly the key is the controller knows when things should happen but it shouldn't know exactly what happens - it triggers the creation with some type info but doesn't know what the type info really means to the `Cards` class. either the factory or the `Cards` class understands the type info and gets the associated images

Comment: Ok understood. But how do I actually assign the images to the array. I mean really basically how to do it. I create a poperty NSMutableArray *fruits; (or a poperty NSMutableArray *clothes; or a poperty NSMutableArray *toys; etc...) then where do I actually write the line: self.fruits = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:"CalliPad.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:"CarryiPad.png"], etc...

Comment: that's what i would put in a factory, so the factory has multiple methods or a switch on an enum with the image names and it creates an array to pass to `Cards` initialiser. if you don't have a factory then i would have controller create and pass it when creating the `Cards` instance

Comment: Ah I think i see what you mean. Thanks a lot for the input. I had no idea you could create a view controller just to manage a class.

Comment: not a view controller, just a controller, a subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: that makes more sense. tx

Comment: +(Cards*) CreateFruitCards{
        fruitCards = [[Cards alloc]initWithObjects:  [UIImage imageNamed:"CalliPad.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:"CarryiPad.png"], etc...];
    } so something like that...
    return sharedData;
}
@end

Comment: sure. from this try to take that allocation of responsibility is the key. create classes and allocate them a set of logical responsibilities. don't cram too much into one class. hence the view controller, card factory, cards model. you'd also likely have a card view, maybe a game view. you can start to look towards MVVM instead of MVC as that also leads to better logical separation